# How to solve this summation Identity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have a summation function $y_n = a^n y_0 + x\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a^i$. I am told that (substitute $n$ with $t$), through summation identities we get

$$y_t = a^ty_0 + x\frac{1-a^t}{1-a}.$$

While I believe the identity, I can't recall what techniques to use to show the equivalence. Can someone give me any tips/hints? I don't neccessarily need a full solution, just a nudge in the right direction thanks

Comment: Do you know how to sum a geometric series? Falling that, since you know what result you want to prove, use induction.

Comment: yes thanks! I see the solution now thank you thank you